# Woocommerce change url of cart and checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My client wants to change the cart url and checkout url to donation summery and donation checkout, not only url but title too because we are working on donation website so we don't want to use cart and checkout.

Cart = Donation Summary

Checkout = Donation Checkout

How can I change easily please help?

Comment: in your `pages` section, you will see these pages - but you can create whatever you want. - inside woocommerce settings, you can select which pages are used for what.

Comment: and how can change the link text for http://mywebsite/donation-checkout/order-received/5194/?key=wc_order_5bfe63ce1dt2b    from order-received to donation-received?

Answer (score 2):

first create two pages in wordpress and put woocommerce shortcode in that content.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

now go to setting woocommerce and change cart pages to custom page url.

Comment: and how can change the link text for http://mywebsite/donation-checkout/order-received/5194/?key=wc_order_5bfe63ce1dt2b    from order-received to donation-received?